# Project Euler #2 (Even Fibonacci numbers): O(1) solution

Tags: c, algorithm, math, numbers, fibonacci

**Project Euler #2 Even Fibonacci Numbers**

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... By considering the terms in the
> Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the
> sum of the even-valued terms.

Question: Is it possible to solve this in constant time?

Comment: Is it a code review you are looking for? If so, post it at (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question. If you're just sharing your solution with us, consider instead asking this problem as a question and posting your solution as an answer to yourself: That would follow the format of this site.

Comment: Binet's formula is not really a constant-time solution for evaluating terms of the Fibonacci sequence, since the required precision goes up as the index goes up (using `double` arithmetic will just break at some point). That doesn't happen if you limit the index to some constant, but that makes *all* implementations constant time (since there is no variable to vary in).

Comment: Note that the Fibonacci sequence is ordinarily defined such that the first *two* positive elements are both 1.  That is, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 , ....  Of course, since you're only adding up the even terms, that doesn't make a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hand-wavy **O(1)-*ish*** solution to PE-2, see comment by @harold :( above. My solution is psuedo-mathematical and not rigorous but hey, it works!

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... By considering the terms in the
> Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the
> sum of the even-valued terms.

**Some building blocks:**

- Binet's formula allows us to compute **F<sub>n</sub>** instantly
- There is another well-known formula for the sum of the first **n** fibonacci number i.e. **F<sub>0</sub> + F<sub>1</sub> + ... + F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n+2</sub> - 1**
- We need a formula for computing the sum of first **k** even numbers of the fibonacci sequence. Let **E<sub>n</sub>** denote the n-th even number in the sequence so **E<sub>1</sub> = 2**. It is well-known that **E<sub>n</sub> = 4E<sub>n-1</sub> - E<sub>n-2</sub>**. Many solutions to this problem utilise this very formula. Doing a bit of math (proof in appendix), you can see that

**E<sub>1</sub> + E<sub>2</sub> + ... + E<sub>k</sub> = (E<sub>k+2</sub> - 3E<sub>k+1</sub> - 2) ÷ 4 = (F<sub>3(k+2)</sub> - 3F<sub>3(k+1)</sub> - 2) ÷ 4** since **E<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>3n</sub>**

- We can compute the above using Binet's formula. The only question that remains is given a bound **X** what should **k** be? We invert Binet's formula to solve for **n** and we get [image]

Rather the ceiling, we floor to get the index **n** of the fibonacci number below **X**. Then we only have to count how many even numbers there are in **{F<sub>0</sub>, ..., F<sub>n</sub>}** and use the formula in Point 3.

**C Implementation:**

I tested it against brute force solutions. Seems to be working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

// Input N
// Output N'th term of fibonacci
unsigned long long binet(int N)
{
    long double phi = (1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;

    return floor((pow(phi, N) / sqrt(5)) + 0.5);
}

int find_fib_n(unsigned long long F_n)
{
    return round(log(sqrt(5) * F_n) / log((1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0));
}

// Input N
// Count of even numbers in the first N fib nums
int count_even_in_fib_seq(int N)
{
    if (N <= 3)
        return 0;

    int tmp = N;

    tmp -= 4;

    return 1 + floor(tmp / 3);
}

#define bound 4000000

int main(void)
{
    int fib_approx_index = find_fib_n(bound);

    printf("%d %llu %d\n", fib_approx_index, binet(fib_approx_index), bound);

    // Number of even numbers below bound
    int K = count_even_in_fib_seq(fib_approx_index + 1);

    printf("count %d\n", K);

    unsigned long long result = (-3 * binet(3 * (K + 1)) + binet(3 * (K + 2)) - 2) / 4;
    printf("%llu", result);
}
```

**Appendix: Formula for sum of the first *k* even fibonacci numbers**

[image: Proof]

After surfacing the web for a while I found some other people who came up with similar solution. Check out these links for more information:

- https://www.xarg.org/puzzle/project-euler/problem-2/
- https://brokensandals.net/technical/programming-challenges/projecteuler-2/

Thanks for reading

Comment: No point in using `long double` with `long double phi = (1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;` and then `pow(phi, N)`.  Use `double`.  If you still want `long double`, use `long double` functions and math: `(1.0L + sqrtl(5)) / 2.0L;` and `powl(phi, N)`.

Comment: `return 1 + floor(tmp / 3)` unnecessarily takes the `int` quotient, converts to `double`, calls `floor()` and then converts the `double` back to `int`.  Simpler to use `return 1 + tmp / 3`.

Comment: Although the math is sound, the implementation to code with `double` floating point math and various roundings may not perform as expected for large `N`.  Perhaps OK for " Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million', yet deserves review.

Comment: "Seems to be working fine." --> With a bound of 40000, this code reports "24 46368 40000", "count 8", "60696", yet the sum I think should be 14328.  Code appears to have added in 46368, yet that is above the  bound.

Comment: This is interesting from a mathematical perspective, but not so much from a *programming* perspective, at least for the specific problem given.  The Fibonacci sequence grows so fast that that there are few terms to add, and in combination with the bound on the terms, it is clear that built-in integer types (`long int`, for sure) are sufficient for the task.  *That* analysis is perhaps the key to the question from the Project Euler perspective.  Having performed it, there's little practical reason to solve this problem other than by brute force.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah I just realised that myself. The problem seems to be in the **find_fib_n** function. Perhaps checking whether **Binet(fib_approx_index)** is above or below the **bound** will improve the solution

Comment: @Haziq It seems that the overall goal is `sum_of_even_fibs(bound)`.  I suspect many FP solutions fail on the edge cases when the _bound_ is near a fib value.  Good luck.

Comment: @Haziq Code reports an incorrect sum on many `bound` values.  Try `bound` = 7 (correct sum 8 not your 7), 27 (10 not 44), 480 (188 not 798), ...  Please fix.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry for the late response. Adding this line `if (binet(fib_approx_index) > bound) fib_approx_index--;` just before **K** is computed resolves the issue. Also for `bound = 7`, I believe the correct sum is **2** since it is the only fibonacci number below **7**. With this fix, the output seems to be consistent with your results

Answer (score 2):

[OEIS](https://oeis.org/A099919) also gives a constant solution:

```
a(n) = (-10 + (5 - 3*sqrt(5))*(2 - sqrt(5))^n + (2 + sqrt(5))^n*(5 + 3*sqrt(5)))/20

-- Colin Barker, Nov 26 2016
```

Tested in Java:

```java
public class Main {

    // https://oeis.org/A099919
    static long a(int n) {
        double sqrt5 = Math.sqrt(5.0);
        return (long)(-10 + (5 - 3 * sqrt5) * Math.pow(2 - sqrt5, n) + Math.pow(2 + sqrt5, n)*(5 + 3*sqrt5))/20;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
            System.out.println(a(n));
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
0
2
10
44
188
798
3382
14328
60696
257114
1089154
4613732
19544084
82790070
350704366
1485607536
6293134512
26658145586
112925716858
478361013020
```

Comment: Is there never a rounding-error for the hole range where `f(n)` fits in a `long`?

Comment: There probably will be. If that is going to happen soon (as in, for a `long`), I do not know (not tested)

Comment: Code does not form an answer based on a given bound. In OP's case, the bound was the Fibonacci number <= four million.  It takes additional non-trivial study to know if the resulting sum in that case is 1,089,154 or 4,613,732.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to solve this in constant time?

The goal implies using an O(1) equation to calculate the sum rather than a simple `puts("4613732");`

Given the limit "terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million", we only need to deal with [Fibonacci(0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) to Fibonacci(38) (3,524,578).  Note that such a small table is easy to make at compile time with the compiler calculating the values - so no run time cost.

An O(1) equation is demonstrated by others using floating point math (FP).

A problem with a floating point solution is that this is an integer problem that deserves an integer solution.  Floating point math has many rounding and inexact computations that render FP approaches questionable for an exact correct answer, especially as `N` grows large.

It is not enough to simply code some math formula in C using FP math for an integer problem.  We need to assess it and determine [when do the wheels fall off](https://memecreator.org/static/images/memes/5509089.jpg).

---

I do not have a better than O(n) integer solution, yet the following can serve as a test harness and reference for those seeking to validate higher value `N` solutions.

It would be interesting to see how far a FP solution can go before it generates incorrect answers.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if 0
typedef uint64_t fib_t;
#define FIB_MAX ULLONG_MAX
#define FIB_BASE10_LEN 20
#define FIBONACCI_INDEX_MAX 93
#else
typedef unsigned __int128 fib_t;
#define FIB_MAX ((fib_t) -1)
#define FIB_BASE10_LEN 39
#define FIBONACCI_INDEX_MAX 186
#endif

#define FIB_STR_N (sizeof(fib_t)*CHAR_BIT + 1)

//                                     v--compound literal--v
#define FIB_STR(x) fibonacci_to_string((char [FIB_STR_N]){""}, (x), 10)

char* fibonacci_to_string(char buf[FIB_STR_N], fib_t i, int base) {
  assert(base >= 2 && base <= 36);
  unsigned ubase = (unsigned) base;
  char *s = &buf[FIB_STR_N - 1];
  *s = '\0';
  do {
    s--;
    unsigned digit = (unsigned) (i % ubase);
    *s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[digit];
    i /= ubase;
  } while (i);
  return s;
}

fib_t fibonacci(unsigned index) {
  static fib_t f[FIBONACCI_INDEX_MAX + 1];
  static unsigned index_size = 0;
  if (index >= index_size) {
    if (index_size < 2) {
      f[0] = 0;
      f[1] = 1;
      index_size = 2;
    } else if (index > FIBONACCI_INDEX_MAX) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Fibonacci index too great %u\n", index);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (index >= index_size) {
      f[index_size] = f[index_size - 1] + f[index_size - 2];
      index_size++;
    }
  }
  return f[index];
}

fib_t sum_of_even_fibonacci(fib_t f_max) {
  fib_t sum = 0;
  fib_t f;
  for (unsigned index = 0; (f = fibonacci(index)) <= f_max; index += 3) {
    if (sum > FIB_MAX - f) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Sum too large f:%s sum:%s\n", FIB_STR(f), FIB_STR(sum));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sum += f;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; 1 && i <= FIBONACCI_INDEX_MAX; i++) {
    printf("%3u %*s\n", i, FIB_BASE10_LEN, FIB_STR(fibonacci(i)));
  }

  printf("Sum of even Fibonacci numbers that do not exceed\n");
  printf("%*s %*s\n", FIB_BASE10_LEN, "limit", FIB_BASE10_LEN, "sum");
  fib_t f_max = FIB_MAX; // 4000000;
  for (fib_t i = 4; i <= f_max; i *= 10) {
    printf("%*s %*s\n", FIB_BASE10_LEN, FIB_STR(i), FIB_BASE10_LEN,
        FIB_STR(sum_of_even_fibonacci(i)));
    if (i >= FIB_MAX / 10)
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
  0                                       0
  1                                       1
  2                                       1
  3                                       2
  4                                       3
  5                                       5
  6                                       8
  7                                      13
  8                                      21
  9                                      34
 10                                      55
 11                                      89
 12                                     144
 13                                     233
 14                                     377
 15                                     610
 16                                     987
 17                                    1597
 18                                    2584
 19                                    4181
 20                                    6765
 21                                   10946
 22                                   17711
 23                                   28657
 24                                   46368
 25                                   75025
 26                                  121393
 27                                  196418
 28                                  317811
 29                                  514229
 30                                  832040
 31                                 1346269
 32                                 2178309
 33                                 3524578
 34                                 5702887
 35                                 9227465
 36                                14930352
 37                                24157817
 38                                39088169
 39                                63245986
 40                               102334155
 41                               165580141
 42                               267914296
 43                               433494437
 44                               701408733
 45                              1134903170
 46                              1836311903
 47                              2971215073
 48                              4807526976
 49                              7778742049
 50                             12586269025
 51                             20365011074
 52                             32951280099
 53                             53316291173
 54                             86267571272
 55                            139583862445
 56                            225851433717
 57                            365435296162
 58                            591286729879
 59                            956722026041
 60                           1548008755920
 61                           2504730781961
 62                           4052739537881
 63                           6557470319842
 64                          10610209857723
 65                          17167680177565
 66                          27777890035288
 67                          44945570212853
 68                          72723460248141
 69                         117669030460994
 70                         190392490709135
 71                         308061521170129
 72                         498454011879264
 73                         806515533049393
 74                        1304969544928657
 75                        2111485077978050
 76                        3416454622906707
 77                        5527939700884757
 78                        8944394323791464
 79                       14472334024676221
 80                       23416728348467685
 81                       37889062373143906
 82                       61305790721611591
 83                       99194853094755497
 84                      160500643816367088
 85                      259695496911122585
 86                      420196140727489673
 87                      679891637638612258
 88                     1100087778366101931
 89                     1779979416004714189
 90                     2880067194370816120
 91                     4660046610375530309
 92                     7540113804746346429
 93                    12200160415121876738
 94                    19740274219868223167
 95                    31940434634990099905
 96                    51680708854858323072
 97                    83621143489848422977
 98                   135301852344706746049
 99                   218922995834555169026
100                   354224848179261915075
101                   573147844013817084101
102                   927372692193078999176
103                  1500520536206896083277
104                  2427893228399975082453
105                  3928413764606871165730
106                  6356306993006846248183
107                 10284720757613717413913
108                 16641027750620563662096
109                 26925748508234281076009
110                 43566776258854844738105
111                 70492524767089125814114
112                114059301025943970552219
113                184551825793033096366333
114                298611126818977066918552
115                483162952612010163284885
116                781774079430987230203437
117               1264937032042997393488322
118               2046711111473984623691759
119               3311648143516982017180081
120               5358359254990966640871840
121               8670007398507948658051921
122              14028366653498915298923761
123              22698374052006863956975682
124              36726740705505779255899443
125              59425114757512643212875125
126              96151855463018422468774568
127             155576970220531065681649693
128             251728825683549488150424261
129             407305795904080553832073954
130             659034621587630041982498215
131            1066340417491710595814572169
132            1725375039079340637797070384
133            2791715456571051233611642553
134            4517090495650391871408712937
135            7308805952221443105020355490
136           11825896447871834976429068427
137           19134702400093278081449423917
138           30960598847965113057878492344
139           50095301248058391139327916261
140           81055900096023504197206408605
141          131151201344081895336534324866
142          212207101440105399533740733471
143          343358302784187294870275058337
144          555565404224292694404015791808
145          898923707008479989274290850145
146         1454489111232772683678306641953
147         2353412818241252672952597492098
148         3807901929474025356630904134051
149         6161314747715278029583501626149
150         9969216677189303386214405760200
151        16130531424904581415797907386349
152        26099748102093884802012313146549
153        42230279526998466217810220532898
154        68330027629092351019822533679447
155       110560307156090817237632754212345
156       178890334785183168257455287891792
157       289450641941273985495088042104137
158       468340976726457153752543329995929
159       757791618667731139247631372100066
160      1226132595394188293000174702095995
161      1983924214061919432247806074196061
162      3210056809456107725247980776292056
163      5193981023518027157495786850488117
164      8404037832974134882743767626780173
165     13598018856492162040239554477268290
166     22002056689466296922983322104048463
167     35600075545958458963222876581316753
168     57602132235424755886206198685365216
169     93202207781383214849429075266681969
170    150804340016807970735635273952047185
171    244006547798191185585064349218729154
172    394810887814999156320699623170776339
173    638817435613190341905763972389505493
174   1033628323428189498226463595560281832
175   1672445759041379840132227567949787325
176   2706074082469569338358691163510069157
177   4378519841510949178490918731459856482
178   7084593923980518516849609894969925639
179  11463113765491467695340528626429782121
180  18547707689471986212190138521399707760
181  30010821454963453907530667147829489881
182  48558529144435440119720805669229197641
183  78569350599398894027251472817058687522
184 127127879743834334146972278486287885163
185 205697230343233228174223751303346572685
186 332825110087067562321196029789634457848
```

More output

```
Sum of even Fibonacci numbers that do not exceed
                                  limit                                     sum
                                      4                                       2
                                     40                                      44
                                    400                                     188
                                   4000                                    3382
                                  40000                                   14328
                                 400000                                  257114
                                4000000                                 4613732
                               40000000                                19544084
                              400000000                               350704366
                             4000000000                              1485607536
                            40000000000                             26658145586
                           400000000000                            478361013020
                          4000000000000                           2026369768940
                         40000000000000                          36361730124070
                        400000000000000                         154030760585064
                       4000000000000000                        2763969850442378
                      40000000000000000                       49597426547377748
                     400000000000000000                      210098070363744836
                    4000000000000000000                     3770056902373173214
                   40000000000000000000                    15970217317495049952
                  400000000000000000000                   286573922006908542050
                 4000000000000000000000                  5142360378806858706956
                40000000000000000000000                 21783388129427422369052
               400000000000000000000000                390887039715493615101718
              4000000000000000000000000               1655824071758491008590040
             40000000000000000000000000              29712557378756321606437562
            400000000000000000000000000             125864412841774744075212130
           4000000000000000000000000000            2258545247825195935704356468
          40000000000000000000000000000           40527950048011752098603204302
         400000000000000000000000000000          171679151392093647435137529168
        4000000000000000000000000000000         3080657373857639014791750813074
       40000000000000000000000000000000        13049874051046942401006156573274
      400000000000000000000000000000000       234170488363228576876271664997964
     4000000000000000000000000000000000      4202018916487067441371883813390086
    40000000000000000000000000000000000     17800037772979229481611438290658376
   400000000000000000000000000000000000    319408717806595170952881986194752746
  4000000000000000000000000000000000000   1353037041234784669179345581755034578
 40000000000000000000000000000000000000  24279264572217720059860402834614598820
```

Answer (score 1):

By Binet's formula,

```
√5 F3m = p^m + q^m
```

where `p` is the cubed Golden ratio and `q` the cubed inverse.

Summing from `0` to `m = n/3` one gets

```
√5 Σ F3m = ((p³)^(m+1) - 1) / (p³-1) - ((q³)^(m+1) - 1) / (q³-1)
```

If floating-point is allowed, this is computed in constant time.

Comment: I think the right-hand-side of your equation should have n's rather than m's.

Comment: @PaulHankin: on second thoughts, it was all wrong. The question relates to the "even-valued terms", which are every *third* terms !

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is it possible to solve this in constant time?

I think OP means O(1) and not *constant time* as functions like `pow()`, `log()` are rarely ever *constant time*.

---

Floating point (FP) approach has troubles.

A *common* problem with FP occurs when one wants *fast* code (O(1)), yet does not realized how often the answer is incorrect or excessively far from the best answer.

Testing is needed.

Sometime rigorous testing is needed.

---

**[OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75409838/2410359) was not apparently tested with various bounds.**

```
correct   bound       sum
ref           0         0
ref           2         2
ref           8        10
ref          34        44
ref         144       188
ref         610       798
ref        2584      3382
ref       10946     14328
ref       46368     60696
ref      196418    257114
ref      832040   1089154
ref     3524578   4613732

Haziq         0         0 
Haziq         2         2 
Haziq         7        10 error
Haziq        27        44 error 
Haziq       114       188 error 
Haziq       480       798 error 
Haziq      2032      3382 error
Haziq      8606     14328 error
Haziq     36453     60696 error
Haziq    154415    257114 error
Haziq    654110   1089154 error
Haziq   2770852   4613732 error
```

**Incorrect results**

`find_fib_n()` is a major culprit.

Using `floor()` instead of `round()` helps reduce the various bound errors:

```
// return round(log(sqrt(5) * F_n) / log((1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0));
return floor(log(sqrt(5) * F_n) / log((1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0));
```

Yet is still not fully correct.

```
Haziq         0         0 
Haziq         2         2 
Haziq         9        10 error 
Haziq        34        44 
Haziq       145       188 error 
Haziq       610       798 
Haziq      2585      3382 error 
Haziq     10946     14328 
Haziq     46369     60696 error 
Haziq    196418    257114 
Haziq    832041   1089154 ... 
Haziq   3524578   4613732
```

To improve further is challenged by the slight errors in the argument to `log()` and that the formula used is not fully correct, but only mathematicaly approximate.

We could try:

```
F_n += (F_n & 1) == 0;
return floor(log2(sqrt(5) * F_n) / log2((1.0 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0));
```

Which returns the correct result over OP's target range (your results may differ). Yet that is not a vetted solution in general.

As it turns out, `F_n += (F_n & 1) == 0;` is better than first thought.

**Deeper**

OP's code hinges on returning a correct value from `find_fib_n(bound)`.  Although that function takes a integer, it could take a `double`. When `bound = some_even_fib_number`, it  returns `i`, yet with `some_even_fib_number - 0.00000001`, it needs to return `i - 1`.  Thus `find_fib_n(bound)` is *very sensitive* to calculation errors when `bound = some_even_fib_number`.

Notice that `find_fib_n(some_even_bound)` is always equal to `find_fib_n(some_even_bound + 1)` and the return  value only change as `bound` increases from `some_odd_bound.9999999` to `the _next_even_bound`.

Incrementing any `even_bound`, we push the floating point calculation away from that sensitive `some_even_fib_number.00000` to `some_even_fib_number + 1`.

This nicely provides more error resilience to OP's calculation.

---

Combined with other silent improves consider:

```
unsigned long long binet(int N) {
  // (sqrt(5) + 1)/2
  #define PHI 1.61803398874989484820458683436564
  #define root5i 0.44721359549995793928183473374626
  double b = pow(PHI, N) * root5i;
  assert(b < (double) LLONG_MAX);
  return (unsigned long long) llround(b);
}

int find_fib_n(unsigned long long F_n) {
  // 1/log2(PHI)
  #define LN2PHIi (1.4404200904125564790175514995879)
  F_n += (F_n & 1) == 0;
  return (int) floor(log2(sqrt(5) * (double)F_n) * LN2PHIi);
}

// Input N
// Count of even numbers in the first N fib nums
int count_even_in_fib_seq(int N) {
  if (N <= 3) {
    return 0;
  }
  int tmp = N;
  tmp -= 4;
  return 1 + tmp / 3;
}
```

---

**Moral of the story**:  Test code for correct functionality before worrying about speed.

---

For reference, follows is a correct and up to a 64-bit sum formed by using integer only math.

```
                    bound                 sum
ref                     0                   0
ref                     2                   2
ref                     8                  10
ref                    34                  44
ref                   144                 188
ref                   610                 798
ref                  2584                3382
ref                 10946               14328
ref                 46368               60696
ref                196418              257114
ref                832040             1089154
ref               3524578             4613732
ref              14930352            19544084
ref              63245986            82790070
ref             267914296           350704366
ref            1134903170          1485607536
ref            4807526976          6293134512
ref           20365011074         26658145586
ref           86267571272        112925716858
ref          365435296162        478361013020
ref         1548008755920       2026369768940
ref         6557470319842       8583840088782
ref        27777890035288      36361730124070
ref       117669030460994     154030760585064
ref       498454011879264     652484772464328
ref      2111485077978050    2763969850442378
ref      8944394323791464   11708364174233842
ref     37889062373143906   49597426547377748
ref    160500643816367088  210098070363744836
ref    679891637638612258  889989708002357094
ref   2880067194370816120 3770056902373173214
```